# ListBox items not selecting (ASP/VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, loops, selected

I have a simple ASPX page with a listbox and a button. Listbox has about 8-10 items in it. After the user selects an item (listbox is multi-select) and clicks the button, I'm iterating through the items to get the selected one like so:

```
    For Each Item As ListItem In lstLetters.Items
        If Item.Selected Then
            Dim LetterID As String
            LetterID = Item.Value
            LetterIDs.Add(LetterID)
        End If
    Next
```

When I step through the code, I select the first item from the listbox. I setup a watch on the 'Item' variable. The code will iterate through each of the items -- but Item.Selected always reads 'False'.

I double-check the page, and sure enough my item is selected on the form.

What the heck is going on?

Thanks in advance,

Jason

Comment: where are you binding your data? can you post your Page_Load ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that maybe you're re-binding the listbox on each postback? That's a common error. Just make sure that you populate the control only if `IsPostBack` is false. Your code seems OK otherwise.

Comment: Now my listbox has no items to iterate through... Frustrating!

Comment: Check your code... On your Page Load or Control Load event you do something like this:

    if (!IsPostback) {
         // ... populate listbox
    }

Right? Then when the user selects something and hits a button you get a postback, and you should be able to get the selection.

Comment: Yes, I'm populating just as you say. But, now there's no items at all to loop through, they've been wiped out.

Comment: Maybe posting some more of your code like @euther suggested would be good. It's difficult to know what's happening.

Comment: D'oh! I put the populate listbox routine in the PostBack 'IF' statement, and totally forgot about the 'ListBox.Items.Clear' statement just two lines above!!! Thanks for your help kprobst!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation happen to me, but it was because the listbox's `Enabled` property was set to `False` in other code. Until I set that to `true`, the selected index remained -1.